# Parsing xml data and writing it on a csv file

Tags: python, xml, csv, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape and save data about prison population and prison
population rates per year and per country from https://www.prisonstudies.org/. These data are
reported in country-specific pages, such as https://www.prisonstudies.org/country/italy.

I must write down the scraped data (for all countries) in a .csv file. This should contain 4 columns:
Country name, Year, Total Prison Population, Prison Population Date

I have done it up to some point, but I am a bit confused for the rest.

An example of expected output: Country name,Year,Total Prison Population,Prison Population Date Algeria,2000,33.992,108 Algeria,2003,39.806,122 Algeria,2004,44.231,134

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import elementpath
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os.path import basename, dirname,abspath

url = "https://www.prisonstudies.org/world-prison-brief-data"

def parseCountries(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = ET.parse(r.text, 'lxml')
    regions = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'item-list'})
    out = {}
    for reg in regions:
        items = reg.findAll('a', href=True)
        for i in items:
            if i.text.strip() != '':
                out[i.text.strip()] = i['href']
    return(out)

def yearTableParser(countryUrl, countryName):
    r = requests.get(countryUrl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    yearTab = soup.find('table', {'id':'views-aggregator-datatable'})
    out = []
    if yearTab is not None:
        rows = yearTab.findAll('tr')
        for r in rows:
            dat = r.findAll('td')
            if dat != []:
                out.append([countryName, dat[0].text.strip(),dat[1].text.replace('c','').replace(',','.').strip(),dat[2].text.replace('c','').replace(',','.').strip()])
    return(out)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your exact expected output from the Italy page?

Comment: @Mathias had an example of the expected output and I added it to my question. The problem is that I have just column names in the.csv file, I can't get the data from the website.

Comment: Your first function delivers no output, use print(out) to see what you get. Debug you first step first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplified answer, addressing only the question of extracting the required data from a page. You can then add the data to your csv, etc.

BTW, the last column name should be `Prison Population Rate`, not `...Date`.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml') #you don't need ElementTree for this.

#use css selectors to extract the data:
table = soup.select('table[id="views-aggregator-datatable"] tbody  tr')

for row in table:
    entry = [td.text.strip() for td in row.select('td')]
    entry.insert(0,countryName)
    print(entry)
```

In the case of Morocco, for example, the output would be:

```
['Morocco', '2000', '54,288', '187']
['Morocco', '2002', '54,351', '184']
['Morocco', '2004', '59,069', '195']
['Morocco', '2006', '53,580', '174']
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced with web scrapping, but I played a bit with this page:
With the idea from [@Jack Fleeting](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9448090/jack-fleeting) I got this result:

Code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib3

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def grap_page(page):
    ### Create dict country name : link part ###
    map_link = {}
    map_county = {}
    soup  = bs.BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser') # lxml, xml, html.parser parser possible
    
    for link in soup.find_all("a"):
        if link.has_attr('href') and "/country/" in link.get("href"):
            map_county[link.string] = link.get('href')
            
    org = 'https://www.prisonstudies.org'        
    for country, uri in map_county.items():
        map_link[country] = org+uri
           
    return map_link

def grap_table(countryName, org_uri):
    ### grep table data ###
    data_list = []
    s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless=new') # normal

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    htm = driver.get(org_uri)
    #print(driver.page_source)
    page = driver.page_source
    soup  = bs.BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
  
    # From answer of Mr. Jack Fleeting
    table = soup.select('table[id="views-aggregator-datatable"] tbody  tr')

    for row in table:
        entry = [td.text.strip() for td in row.select('td')]
        entry.insert(0, countryName)
        if entry not in data_list:
            data_list.append(entry)
    return data_list
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Step 1: get the country links
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    url = 'https://www.prisonstudies.org/world-prison-brief-data'
    r = http.request('GET', url)
    country_dic = grap_page(r.data)
    
    # Step 2: read the table data from country page
    
    # Dummy for development only    
    tab = grap_table('algerien', 'https://www.prisonstudies.org/country/algeria') #link
    for row in tab:
        print(row)
    
    """ For scrapping all pages 
    for country, link in country_dic.items():
        tab = grap_table(country, link)
        print(tab) ### write it to css file
    """
```

Output for Algeria, I run not all pages, but it should work the same:

```
['algerien', '2000', '33,992', '108']
['algerien', '2003', '39,806', '122']
['algerien', '2004', '44,231', '134']
['algerien', '2006', '54,117', '159']
['algerien', '2008', '55,598', '158']
['algerien', '2010', '58,000', '161']
['algerien', '2012', '55,000', '147']
['algerien', '2014', '61,000', '155']
['algerien', '2016', 'c 60,000', 'c 148']
['algerien', '2018', 'c 63,000', 'c 151']
```